# How to dynamically update the input text field value in angular formly?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-formly

I am using `angular-formly` in the angular 4 projects.
The scenario of the work is I have the list of the users and each user has got edit and delete button.

When a user clicks on the edit button a modal is shown up with 2 fields, one is an email address and another one to change the role of the user.

I am using `<formly-form>` to render the form onto the modal like this.

[image]

When edit button is clicked this modal gets opened, where I wanted to show the email address which is associated with the edit button which is clicked.

Also, I want to keep the role selected in the dropdown for that user.

Here is the formlyfieldconfig

```
{
        key: 'email',
        className: 'col-sm-4',
        type: 'input',
        defaultValue: '',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Email',
            disabled: true,
            placeholder: ''
        }
    },
    {
        key: 'role',
        className: 'col-sm-4',
        type: 'select',
        defaultValue: '',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Select Role',
            options: [],
            required: true
        }
    }
```

As you can see, above for email field I have kept defaultValue as null, whereas for role field I have kept defaultValue and options as null.

When a user clicks on the edit button, I am dynamically setting the defaultValue and options property which should reflect in the modal popup form.

```
private edituser(account):void {        
        this.updateModal.show();
        let userData = updateuserdata;

        this._PicklistApi.findById('5c45b9e06c0bbc57b5d43a66')
            .subscribe(picklist => {
                if(picklist && picklist['options'].length) {

                    _.find(userData,{'key': 'email'})
                        .defaultValue = account.email;

                    _.find(userData,{'key': 'role'})
                        .defaultValue = account.role;

                        _.find(userData,{'key': 'role'})
                        .templateOptions.options = [...picklist['options']];


                }
        });

        this.updateuserdata = userData;                      
    }
```

`this._PicklistApi` is a service object which will give me the list of all roles available.

`updateuserdata` will have the actual form field config which is passed to the `<formly-form>` component in HTML.

`account` parameter is user object having user data including email and role.

when a user clicks on the edit button `edituser()` gets called, and it sets the select options properly with the available roles.

But, it is not setting up defaultValue for both the email and role fields.

I am not able to understand this behavior as select options are getting set properly whereas it is not setting up the defaultValue for both the fields.

If I do console log then I do see that defaultValue is set for the both of the fields then why it isn't reflecting in the form.

Comment: formly take account of `defaultValue` only on initialization, so what you're looking for is `_.find(userData,{'key': 'email'}).formControl.setValue(account.email)`

Comment: You saved my life man, thanks for this answer it worked for me. By the way is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @a.aitboudad Why not adding an accepted response if it fixed it ?